# ZScalar 'proceed' with download with wget

Tags: command-line, powershell, download, wget

I am using PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest` (alias `wget`) to download miniconda.  When using the Windows 10 GUI, Zscaler will warn me, but I can still click on the "Continue" button to continue with the download.

How do I continue when downloading from the command line?  I don't see any options.  Are there any options to wrap this in a Zscaler CLI command?

```
PS> wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe -OutFile "Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe"
wget : 
C03Are you sure you want to visit this site? 
You tried to visit: https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe
You are downloading exe filetype from a site categorized as Information Technology 
Proceeding to visit the site may violate your company policy. Press the "Continue" button to access the site anyway or press the "Back" button on your browser to go back 
    See our internet use policy. 
Need help? Contact our support team at +1.555.555.5555, IT-Service@acme.com 
Your organization has selected Zscaler to protect you from internet threats. 

PS>
```

Comment: Have you contacted anyone at your company about how to approach this?

Comment: This is not a PowerShell code issue, it's your company security/risk policy controls. They don't want you doing this. Asking the public web to help you try and circumvent your company security/risk management policy, is really not prudent. Even if we did, and you are caught doing this, it could mean disciplinary actions by your organization against you.  Meaning RPE (resume producing event) or CLM (career-limiting move) events.YOu need to talk to your policy folks.

Comment: @postanote  I already have the option to "allow" this through the GUI, finding out a way to do this from the CLI is not circumventing anything.

Comment: Again, if you this from a different machine (home device or from public wifi), not in your company/via a non-corporate device, you will find it downloads as expected, with no other prompts. What you are can do and or allowed to do via GUI is a completely different thing than doing it via automation as per corporate filtering policies. I have downloaded/build routines/recipes that are part of our CI/CD for what you are doing as well as more and all work without issue. In another customer site, the same approach fails, because of their filtering policies.

Comment: the message you see is literally the exact same message you get in the GUI, only in the CLI you can't ' Press the "Continue" button' because that button does not exist.  I am looking for a CLI equivalent to what is already present in the GUI tool like responding with 'Type [Y]es to continue' like other CLI tools.